# Haskell io-streams and `forever` produces no output to stdout

Tags: haskell

If I run this program, I get no output to `stdout`:

```
import Control.Monad (forever)
import qualified System.IO.Streams as S
import System.Random (randomRIO)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  is <- S.makeInputStream $ forever $ (randomRIO (1, 100) :: IO Int)
  os <- printStream =<< S.read is
  return ()

printStream :: Maybe Int -> IO ()
printStream Nothing  = putStrLn "Nada!"
printStream (Just a) = putStrLn $ show a
```

I have tried setting buffering using `System.IO.hSetBuffering` to `LineBuffering` and `NoBuffering` but still no output. I've tried `cat | ~/local/bin/program | cat` but again, nothing in stdout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The meaning of the `forever` in your code is that it takes for ever to choose *each* value in the stream. Its type

```
forever :: Monad m => m a -> m b
```

is a big clue that a computation built with `forever` never returns a value: the caller of `forever` gets to pick the type `b` arbitrarily, so no program can actually promise to deliver a value of that type. That's also why your program typechecks. The computation you pass to `forever` is repeatedly executed for its effect (in this case, choosing a random number), but no value is ever delivered, hence the stream never gets going.

You shouldn't need a `forever` to make a stream that keeps going. The behaviour of `makeInputStream` is to run its argument computation each time a value is demanded from the stream, so you've got your repetition there already.

Comment: Thank you! I was reading `forever` as a transformation of sorts, so it would return a `IO Int` (in this case) which I can then pull a value from. I've moved that call to the output stream line and it works as intended! :)

Comment: I've been saying they should change it to `forever :: Monad m => m () -> m Void`!

Comment: "You can talk till you're blue in the face..."

Comment: @Gurkenglas, aside from the fact that doing so would break everyone's code, it would also have efficiency implications. `<$` isn't always free. There are definitely times when requiring `()` would prevent mistakes (I ran face-first into that once), but it costs. Using `Void` instead of a polymorphic return type has no benefit that I can see.

Comment: @dfeuer, in this case, `S.makeInputStream` would return a stream of Void, and the compiler would have told him he's trying to Show Void. () prevents the mistake of throwing away information unless you explicitly do fmap (const ()), and Void prevents its dual mistake of pulling information out of infinity unless you explicitly do fmap absurd.

Comment: If `forever` and similar devices didn't have a polymorphic return type, things like the pipes library would become impenetrable, since every application of `>->` presupposes that the linked pipes or coroutines have the same return type. Thus typically in `p >-> q >-> r` all but one will be infinite; the result of the finite pipe is the result of the composed pipe, which is also finite. This arises by specialization.

Comment: Similarly wherever you can think of an `Alternative` instance having the character of 'racing' the things given to `<|>`, `empty` will be like this, as will many natural terms. Thus in `async` we can write something like  `stillWorking = Concurrently (forever (threadDelay 100000 >> putStrLn "Still working ..."))` and `conc <|> stillWorking` will tell us that conc is working as long as it is. This again arises by simple specialization.